# Resolving "discrete value supplied to continuous scale" error when attempting to edit binary logistic regression plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, sjplot

I am using a binary logistic regression model to investigate the causes of populism in Denmark using the below regression model:

```
Denmark <- glm(popvt ~ trstprl + trstplt + stfgov + stfdem + mnactic + agegroup + eisced, 
               data = dktrim, 
               family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```

Where popvt is a two-level factor, trstprl/trstplt/stfgov/stfdem a set of integers ranging from 0-10, and mnactic, agegroup and eisced are four-, four- and three-level factors respectively.

After successfully running the regression I used sjPlot's plot_model to obtain a plot model of odds ratios for each independent variable, as shown here:
[Plot of Odds Ratios in explaining support for populist parties in Denmark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAFcC.png) through this code:

```
plot_DK <- plot_model(Denmark)
```

I would like to reduce the scale of the x-axis for odds ratios to between 0.1 and 5.

But when I attempt to do so with the following I get the error:

> **Scale for 'x' is already present. Adding another scale for 'x',
>   which will replace the existing scale. Error: Discrete value supplied
>   to continuous scale**

```
plot_DK + xlim(0.1, 5)
```

I had the same error when I used:

```
plot_DK + scale_x_continuous(0.1, 5)
```

I know that ggplot2 and sjPlot are definitely compatible as I was able to recolour the plot despite being unable to change the x-axis.

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Maybe you could use the `axis.lim` parameter of the `plot_model` function to specify direclty the x axis when defining the plot..